# Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'jmsinqueue' - retrying in 5000 ms

Tags: spring, apache-camel, hornetq, spring-jms, wildfly

Goal  to connect to Hornteq and send a message to a queue and route it to a topic or queue and see the contents  in the queue and topic after routing and before routing 
but am getting the error of :

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'jmsinqueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following keys are invalid for configuring a connector: http-upgrade-endpoint
```

Below is the description and output of the program.
2 Question :How can i use the Java DSL as i have used in the context-xml and send a  queue to hornetq route it using camel process it and route to an output queue .I have done research but i am still a newbie on this your advice and help will be greatly appreciated...
reason of this i will be able to use apache camel for all the integration with hornetq and not activemq.
Am using a jndi connection to communicate to wildFly and within the context-xml  i have the following

```
 <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">http-remoting://localhost:8080</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">testuser</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">password</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

     <bean id="mylogger" class="org.apache.camel.component.log.LogComponent"/>
  <bean id="logMessageOnTimerEvent"
        class="com.naistech.camelhornetq.LogMessageOnTimerEventRouteBuilder"/>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="logMessageOnTimerEvent"/>
  </camelContext>
     <camel:camelContext id="context1">
        <camel:route id="FirstRoute">
<!--            <camel:from uri="jms:queue:inputqueue"/>-->
            <camel:from uri="jms:queue:jmsinqueue"/>
            <camel:log logName="jmsLog" message="Got message from JMS queue:"/>
            <camel:to uri="jms:topic:helloworld"/>
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

And then i create the queues and topics  using jboss-cli  :

when i run the  program which is 
 Note i left the imports

```
public class SpringJavaDslApplication extends RouteBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
        applicationContext.start();

        // let the Camel runtime do its job for 5 seconds
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
         SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        // add POJOs to the registry here using registry.put("name", <object reference>)

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);

        context.addComponent("mylogger", new LogComponent());
        context.addRoutes(new LogMessageOnTimerEventRouteBuilder());

        context.start();

        // let the Camel runtime do its job for 5 seconds
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // shutdown
        context.stop();



        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        // shutdown
        applicationContext.stop();

    }

    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("jms:queue:someQueue")
                .to("jms:queue:someOtherQueue");
    }
}
```

i get the following output in the console

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ camelHornetq-wildfly ---
2014-02-28 14:28:15,196 [main           ] INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6d4b8027: startup date [Fri Feb 28 14:28:15 EAT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-02-28 14:28:15,243 [main           ] INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader        - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]
2014-02-28 14:28:16,441 [main           ] INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Overriding bean definition for bean 'template': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.apache.camel.spring.CamelProducerTemplateFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.apache.camel.spring.CamelProducerTemplateFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2014-02-28 14:28:16,441 [main           ] INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Overriding bean definition for bean 'consumerTemplate': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.apache.camel.spring.CamelConsumerTemplateFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.apache.camel.spring.CamelConsumerTemplateFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2014-02-28 14:28:16,518 [main           ] INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@35c5acda: defining beans [jndiTemplate,jmsQueueConnectionFactory,jms,mylogger,logMessageOnTimerEvent,camel-1:beanPostProcessor,camel-1,context1:beanPostProcessor,context1]; root of factory hierarchy
2014-02-28 14:28:16,606 [main           ] INFO  xnio                           - XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
2014-02-28 14:28:16,671 [main           ] INFO  nio                            - XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
2014-02-28 14:28:16,741 [main           ] INFO  remoting                       - JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
2014-02-28 14:28:17,131 [ndpoint" task-6] ERROR RemoteNamingStoreV1            - Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID e2358a57 (outbound) of Remoting connection 550661b8 to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
2014-02-28 14:28:17,592 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2014-02-28 14:28:17,593 [main           ] INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy      - JMX is enabled
2014-02-28 14:28:17,717 [main           ] INFO  DefaultTypeConverter           - Loaded 176 type converters
2014-02-28 14:28:17,888 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2014-02-28 14:28:17,937 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://logMessageTimer?period=1s]
2014-02-28 14:28:17,949 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
2014-02-28 14:28:17,954 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.359 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:17,958 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: context1) is starting
2014-02-28 14:28:17,958 [main           ] INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy      - JMX is enabled
2014-02-28 14:28:17,979 [main           ] INFO  DefaultTypeConverter           - Loaded 176 type converters
2014-02-28 14:28:18,039 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2014-02-28 14:28:18,103 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Route: FirstRoute started and consuming from: Endpoint[jms://queue:jmsinqueue]
2014-02-28 14:28:18,111 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
2014-02-28 14:28:18,112 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: context1) started in 0.153 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:18,973 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-1, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:18 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:18,993 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:18 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:19,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-3, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:19 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:19,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:19 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:20,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-5, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:20 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:20,938 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:20 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:21,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-7, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:21 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:21,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:21 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:22,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-9, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:22 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:22,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:22 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:23,116 [mer[jmsinqueue]] INFO  ultJmsMessageListenerContainer - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
2014-02-28 14:28:23,116 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-4) is starting
2014-02-28 14:28:23,116 [main           ] INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy      - JMX is enabled
2014-02-28 14:28:23,117 [mer[jmsinqueue]] ERROR ultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'jmsinqueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following keys are invalid for configuring a connector: http-upgrade-endpoint
2014-02-28 14:28:23,343 [main           ] INFO  DefaultTypeConverter           - Loaded 176 type converters
2014-02-28 14:28:23,374 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2014-02-28 14:28:23,399 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://logMessageTimer?period=1s]
2014-02-28 14:28:23,403 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
2014-02-28 14:28:23,403 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-4) started in 0.287 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:23,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-11, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:23 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:23,938 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:23 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:24,399 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-2-1, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:24 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:24,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route2                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:24 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:24,936 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-13, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:24 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:24,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:24 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:25,399 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-2-3, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:25 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:25,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route2                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:25 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:25,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-15, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:25 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:25,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:25 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:26,399 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-2-5, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:26 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:26,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route2                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:26 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:26,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-17, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:26 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:26,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:26 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:27,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-2-7, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:27 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:27,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route2                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:27 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:27,937 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-0-19, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:27 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:27,938 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route1                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:27 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:28,118 [mer[jmsinqueue]] ERROR ultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'jmsinqueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following keys are invalid for configuring a connector: http-upgrade-endpoint
2014-02-28 14:28:28,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  insideTheRoute                 - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-naistech-53400-1393586897419-2-9, firedTime=Fri Feb 28 14:28:28 EAT 2014}, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
2014-02-28 14:28:28,400 [logMessageTimer] INFO  route2                         - Event triggered by logMessageTimer at Fri Feb 28 14:28:28 EAT 2014
2014-02-28 14:28:28,403 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-4) is shutting down
2014-02-28 14:28:28,404 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2014-02-28 14:28:28,407 [ - ShutdownTask] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Route: route2 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[timer://logMessageTimer?period=1s]
2014-02-28 14:28:28,407 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:28,412 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-4) uptime 5.295 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:28,412 [main           ] INFO  DefaultCamelContext            - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-4) is shutdown in 0.008 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:28,412 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
2014-02-28 14:28:28,412 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2014-02-28 14:28:28,413 [ - ShutdownTask] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[timer://logMessageTimer?period=1s]
2014-02-28 14:28:28,413 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:28,416 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 10.826 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:28,416 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.004 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:28,416 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: context1) is shutting down
2014-02-28 14:28:28,416 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2014-02-28 14:28:33,119 [ - ShutdownTask] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Route: FirstRoute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[jms://queue:jmsinqueue]
2014-02-28 14:28:33,119 [main           ] INFO  DefaultShutdownStrategy        - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 4 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:33,122 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: context1) uptime 15.164 seconds
2014-02-28 14:28:33,122 [main           ] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Apache Camel 2.12.2 (CamelContext: context1) is shutdown in 4.706 seconds
```

On the wildFly side it just outputs the following when i run the Program above.

14:28:17,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (default task-12) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 62358a57 (inbound) of Remoting connection 78dd3e11 to /127.0.0.1:49754

Where am i going wrong ... kindly advice .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure are you using the same version of HornetQ for Camel than for WildFly.

From the error, you are not using the same (it should be HornetQ 2.4.1.Final)

Comment: in my pom.xml i have  Hornetq-jms-client  
      <version>2.4.1.Final</version>

Comment: Thanks  i have had a second look and i have found  in my pom.xml i have both 2.4.0 and  hornetq-jms-client with version 2.4.1